# Regex and patterns on a ksh command line

Tags: command-line, regular-expression, wildcards

I'm wondering what's the difference between using `*` and `.*` in a regex string.

I guess, `*` stands for "0 to n characters" but I don't see what `.*` stands for.

For example, what is the difference between: `"2013*11*27"` and `"2013.*11.*27"`?
If I take a look to

```
find . -name [pattern]
```

As pattern I tried : `"2013.*11.*25"` and it didn't find `"2013-11-25"` however, with `"2013*11*25"`, it finds it.

Why ? 
In unix, 0 or n occurences of wildcards is : `*`, in regex `.*` so why doesn't it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` stands for *0 or more arbitrary characters* in **shell wildcard** matches.

`*` stands for *0 or more occurrences of **the preceding expression***  in **regex** matches.

`.` stands for *single arbitrary character* in **regex** matches.

Thus, `*` in shell wildcard match is equivalent to `.*` in regex match.

"2013*11*27" in *regex match* will match `"2013333111111111127"` but not `"2013-11-27"` but if you use it to find files, e.g. as argument to `ls`, letting the shell handle it as "shell wildcard match" (and not regex) it will capture `"2013-11-27"` just fine.

*<sub>(in your case, the expression is a single character matching exactly that character, `3` and `1` respectively.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to separate regexp from unix shell pattern.
In ksh command expect special option, you will use unix pattern.
if you use for example grep -R you will use regexp.

The `*` in regex synthax mean 0 or n occurences.
The `*` in unix pattern mean any string and depending on the settings with or without line jump.
If you use regexp `.*` means any char except jump line  0 or n time
and using `*` in a regex will match the previous char 0 or n time.

`.*` in regexp is equivalent of unix pattenr `*`

`find -name` use unix pattern so using `.*` in a pattern stand for finding `.ANY_STRING_OR_NO_STRING` no any sring.
tu use regexp use
`find -regex`

Regard

Comment: I'm still missing something. If I do :
find . -name [pattern]

As pattern I tried : "2013.*11.*25" and it didn't find "2013-11-25" however, with "2013*11*25", it finds it. 

If I take a look to what you wrote above, in regexp, I should used .* to say "0 or n occurences of wild card"

Comment: ``find -name` use pattern and not regexp so `.*` in your search stand for `2013.anystring11.anystring225`. You must use `find -regexp` to use regexp instaed pattern

Comment: Ok Thank you.

However, by default, grep use regexp ?

Comment: no to use regexp in grep you must provide the argumen `-R`. You should consider the use of `man grep` or any man ;)

Comment: Yeah, but actually I thought that in man pages, pattern was used for regexp. But ok thank you.